# C# Decompilation

Tags: c#, .net, decompiling

I was just browsing through some of my own code in Telerik's JustDecompile and noticed that the following code

```
   switch (data.CurrentSection) 
   {
    case SurveyData.CurrentSectionEnum.Section1:
        divSection1.Visible = true;
        divSection2.Visible = false;
        divSection3.Visible = false;
        break;
    case SurveyData.CurrentSectionEnum.Section2:
        divSection1.Visible = false;
        divSection2.Visible = true;
        divSection3.Visible = false;
        break;
    case SurveyData.CurrentSectionEnum.Section3:
        divSection1.Visible = false;
        divSection2.Visible = false;
        divSection3.Visible = true;
        break;
    }
```

Was displayed as

```
switch (data.CurrentSection)
{
    case CurrentSectionEnum.Section1:
    {
        this.divSection1.set_Visible(true);
        this.divSection2.set_Visible(false);
        this.divSection3.set_Visible(false);
        break;
    }
    case CurrentSectionEnum.Section2:
    {
        this.divSection1.set_Visible(false);
        this.divSection2.set_Visible(true);
        this.divSection3.set_Visible(false);
        break;
    }
    case CurrentSectionEnum.Section3:
    {
        this.divSection1.set_Visible(false);
        this.divSection2.set_Visible(false);
        this.divSection3.set_Visible(true);
        break;
    }
}
```

Was this an artefact of the Telerik Decompiler or could my hunch be correct that no 'set using equals sign' operator exists at some lower level part of the framework? If so could anyone provide more info?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Properties and Methods](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1209359/properties-and-methods)

Comment: Clearly is not a very good decompiler.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Properties are a construct of the C# (and VB.Net too) language, not the CLR. They are implemented as get_XXX and set_XXX methods.

I would expect the decompiler to recognize them!

Comment: That's not really true. Properties do exists at the CLR level (see e.g. `PropertyInfo`), but you're right that setter and getter are just methods.

Comment: You're right - the assembly does include metadata describing the property. Another reason why the decompiler should pick them up.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have the latest version of JustDecompile. I tried your code with version 2012.1.214.2 and it is generating the C# you would expect.

As mentioned in one of the comments, the getter and setters are just methods. Here is the how the calls look in IL:

```
ldloc.0
ldc.i4.1
callvirt instance void DivSection::set_Visible(bool)
```