# I cannot set and call value using setter and getter

Tags: c#

**Learning Setter and Getter**

I am making a console log app where I create a Box class and make an object and set values: width, height, and length using setter and getter. I was referencing [an solution on github](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15376840/how-do-i-call-a-getter-or-setter-in-c-sharp), but I haven't make it work yet. I don't know where I made mistake.

**My Code**

```cs
using System;

namespace ClassDemo2
{
    class Box
    {
        private double _width;
        private double _height;
        private double _length;

        public double Width
        {
            get { return _width; }
            set { this._width = Width; }
        }

        public double Height
        {
            get { return _height; }
            set { this._height = Height; }
        }

        public double Length
        {
            get { return _length; }
            set {this._length = Length; }
        }

        public double volume()
        {
            return Width * Height * Length;
        }

    }

    public class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Box box = new Box();

            //Set value
            box.Width = 12;
            box.Height = 12;
            box.Length = 12;

            //Get value
            double width = box.Width;
            double height = box.Height;
            double length = box.Length;

            Console.WriteLine("Box properties");
            Console.WriteLine("Width: {0}", width);
            Console.WriteLine("Height: {0}", height);
            Console.WriteLine("Length: {0}", length);
            Console.WriteLine("Volume: {0}", box.volume());
        }
    }

}
```

**Console Window**

[image]

Comment: why do you have empty setters like `set { ; }` ? they basically do nothing, effectively making your objects readonly

Comment: `set { this._width = value; }`

Comment: In C#, a setter must always use **`value`** as in: `set { this._width = value; }`. Same for the other properties.

Comment: @Iłya Bursov thanks for pointing that out, I was copy pasting code and somehow I thought `set{ ; }` automatically set the value. but even I added some code in there, the resul on console window is the same

Comment: @kawa that would be `set;` without the {}. But then your getter should also be automatic and there is no private field, as shown in RCS' answer.

Comment: That's not what tags are for; they're for categorizing questions.  Java people who know C# will be looking at the C# tag.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The setters in the Box class aren't doing anything. The setters aren't assigning a value to the private fields in the Box class.

You may as well remove the fields altogether and use [auto-implemented properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/auto-implemented-properties).

For example:

```
class Box
{
    public double Width { get; set; }

    public double Height { get; set; }

    public double Length { get; set; }

    public double Volume()
    {
        return Width * Height * Length;
    }
}
```

Comment: Perhaps you can expand the code example to show the whole class, to emphasize that when using auto properties you don't need the `private double ...` anymore

Comment: This is very simple! thanks! 
`public string FirstName { get; set; } = "Jane";` it's cool that you can also declare a default value like this.
Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

```
    class Box
    {
        public double Width { get; set; }
        public double Height { get; set; }
        public double Length { get; set; }

        public double volume()
        {
            return Width * Height * Length;
        }
    }
```

Use Auto-Implemented Properties (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/auto-implemented-properties)